# An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator in Amadues Self Production API

Tags: amadeus

We Get Following Error in Amadeus Self Live API.

```json
{"errors": [{"code": 38189,"title": "Internal error","detail": "An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator","status": 500}]}
```

Can anyone Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I get the same issue with POST flight offer pricing call, i need help, thanks